# AngularJS- Login and Authentication in each route and controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-authentication

I have an AngularJS application created by using yeoman, grunt and bower.

I have a login page that has a controller that checks for authentication. If the credentials are correct I reroute to home page.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
//Define Routing for app
angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      })
    .when('/forgotPassword', {
        templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
        controller: 'forgotController'
      })
   .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
       controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/login'
    });
//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
}]);

angular.module('myApp').factory("page", function($rootScope){
    var page={};
    var user={};
    page.setPage=function(title,bodyClass){
        $rootScope.pageTitle = title;
        $rootScope.bodylayout=bodyClass;
    };
    page.setUser=function(user){
        $rootScope.user=user;
    }
    return page;
});
```

**LoginControler.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $window,page) {
    page.setPage("Login","login-layout");
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.loginUser=function()
    {
        var username=$scope.user.name;
        var password=$scope.user.password;
        if(username=="admin" && password=="admin123")
        {
            page.setUser($scope.user);
            $location.path( "/home" );
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.message="Error";
            $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
        }
    }
});
```

On the home page I have

```
<span class="user-info">
    <small>Welcome,</small>
    {{user.name}}
</span>
<span class="logout"><a href="" ng-click="logoutUser()">Logout</a></span>
```

In the `loginController`, I check the login info and if it's successful, I set the user object in the service factory. I don't know whether this is correct or not.

What I need is, When the user is logged in, It sets some value in the user object so that all other pages can get that value.

Whenever any route changes happen, the controller should check if the user is logged in or not. If not, it should reroute to the login page. Also, if the user is already logged in and come back to the page, it should go to home page. The controller should also check the credentials on all of the routes.

I have heard about ng-cookies, but I don't know how to use them.

Many of the examples I saw were not very clear and they use some kind of access roles or something. I don't want that. I only want a login filter.
Can someone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

My solution breaks down in 3 parts: the state of the user is stored in a service, in the run method you watch when the route changes and you check if the user is allowed to access the requested page, in your main controller you watch if the state of the user change.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {

        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log('DENY');
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        else {
            console.log('ALLOW');
            $location.path('/home');
        }
    });
}]);
```

You should create a service (I will name it `Auth`) which will handle the user object and have a method to know if the user is logged or not.

**service**:

```
 .factory('Auth', function(){
var user;

return{
    setUser : function(aUser){
        user = aUser;
    },
    isLoggedIn : function(){
        return(user)? user : false;
    }
  }
})
```

From your `app.run`, you should listen the `$routeChangeStart` event. When the route will change, it will check if the user is logged (the `isLoggedIn` method should handle it). It won't load the requested route if the user is not logged and it will redirect the user to the right page (in your case login).

The `loginController` should be used in your login page to handle login. It should just interract with the `Auth` service and set the user as logged or not.

**loginController**:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Auth', function ($scope, Auth) {
  //submit
  $scope.login = function () {
    // Ask to the server, do your job and THEN set the user

    Auth.setUser(user); //Update the state of the user in the app
  };
}])
```

From your main controller, you could listen if the user state change and react with a redirection.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', function ($scope, Auth, $location) {

  $scope.$watch(Auth.isLoggedIn, function (value, oldValue) {

    if(!value && oldValue) {
      console.log("Disconnect");
      $location.path('/login');
    }

    if(value) {
      console.log("Connect");
      //Do something when the user is connected
    }

  }, true);
```

Comment: Ok. What should be in my loginController? I mean what I should set?

Comment: The loginController will permit the user to login from the login page. It will handle the login form. The form have to call a submit method which is part of your loginController. This method will update (if the form is correct and the user have to be logged in) the state of the user USING the Auth service I described.

Comment: Sorry, Can you show how to write the service and how to set that in LoginController?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Instead of the provided service I used [Auth0 with AngularJS](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular).

Comment: I like @gab solution, but I am not sure I understand the need for both the code in the `app.run` and then in the main controller with `$scope.watch`... don't then do the same thing? is it not redundant? Sorry if I am missing something obvious here, still getting used to ng...

Comment: app.run code will only redirect when the route change. $scope.watch will watch the state of the user and will do redirect even if the route isn't updated. But it remains optional. In my case, if the "user" object become null for whatever reason (like a logout), the redirection will happen. It depends on your application, you may want to trigger redirection manually for login and logout action. If the state of the user can't change you don't need to watch anything. Hope that help. Sorry for my approximative english.

Comment: What if the user hits F5 and refreshes? Then your in memory Auth is gone.

Comment: Thanks nice trick. I have question.. .run() is call everytime when new controller loaded so we need to check Auth in every controller? If have to give access to some pages when user is login or not login then what i can do? i am redirect to dashboard page everytime. so i think i have to change page manually in .run(). but i dont known it is best way to do that. please help. Thanks

Comment: Just in case others have problems getting this example to run:

in the `routeChangeStart` callback you should check whether the location is actually "/login" and allow that:
`if ( $location.path() === "/login" ) return;`

Comment: it get me in infinite loop.

Comment: I removed the "event.preventDefault();" code in the run method of app and it started working fine for me.  What did I miss here ??

Comment: Note if you're using UI router, `$stateChangeStart` was depreciated. Instead you'll have to use UI router transition hooks like so:

`app.run(function($transitions, Auth) {
  $transitions.onStart({ to: 'auth.**' }, function(trans) {
    if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      // User isn't authenticated. Redirect to a new Target State
      return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
    }
  });
})`

Answer (score 114):

Here is another possible solution, using the `resolve` attribute of the [`$stateProvider`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state) or the [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). Example with `$stateProvider`:

```js
.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state("forbidden", {
    /* ... */
  })

  .state("signIn", {
    /* ... */
    resolve: {
      access: ["Access", function (Access) { return Access.isAnonymous(); }],
    }
  })

  .state("home", {
    /* ... */
    resolve: {
      access: ["Access", function (Access) { return Access.isAuthenticated(); }],
    }
  })

  .state("admin", {
    /* ... */
    resolve: {
      access: ["Access", function (Access) { return Access.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"); }],
    }
  });

}])
```

`Access` resolves or rejects a promise depending on the current user rights:

```js
.factory("Access", ["$q", "UserProfile", function ($q, UserProfile) {

  var Access = {

    OK: 200,

    // "we don't know who you are, so we can't say if you're authorized to access
    // this resource or not yet, please sign in first"
    UNAUTHORIZED: 401,

    // "we know who you are, and your profile does not allow you to access this resource"
    FORBIDDEN: 403,

    hasRole: function (role) {
      return UserProfile.then(function (userProfile) {
        if (userProfile.$hasRole(role)) {
          return Access.OK;
        } else if (userProfile.$isAnonymous()) {
          return $q.reject(Access.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
          return $q.reject(Access.FORBIDDEN);
        }
      });
    },

    hasAnyRole: function (roles) {
      return UserProfile.then(function (userProfile) {
        if (userProfile.$hasAnyRole(roles)) {
          return Access.OK;
        } else if (userProfile.$isAnonymous()) {
          return $q.reject(Access.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
          return $q.reject(Access.FORBIDDEN);
        }
      });
    },

    isAnonymous: function () {
      return UserProfile.then(function (userProfile) {
        if (userProfile.$isAnonymous()) {
          return Access.OK;
        } else {
          return $q.reject(Access.FORBIDDEN);
        }
      });
    },

    isAuthenticated: function () {
      return UserProfile.then(function (userProfile) {
        if (userProfile.$isAuthenticated()) {
          return Access.OK;
        } else {
          return $q.reject(Access.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
      });
    }

  };

  return Access;

}])
```

`UserProfile` copies the current user properties, and implement the `$hasRole`, `$hasAnyRole`, `$isAnonymous` and `$isAuthenticated` methods logic (plus a `$refresh` method, explained later):

```js
.factory("UserProfile", ["Auth", function (Auth) {

  var userProfile = {};

  var clearUserProfile = function () {
    for (var prop in userProfile) {
      if (userProfile.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        delete userProfile[prop];
      }
    }
  };

  var fetchUserProfile = function () {
    return Auth.getProfile().then(function (response) {
      clearUserProfile();
      return angular.extend(userProfile, response.data, {

        $refresh: fetchUserProfile,

        $hasRole: function (role) {
          return userProfile.roles.indexOf(role) >= 0;
        },

        $hasAnyRole: function (roles) {
          return !!userProfile.roles.filter(function (role) {
            return roles.indexOf(role) >= 0;
          }).length;
        },

        $isAnonymous: function () {
          return userProfile.anonymous;
        },

        $isAuthenticated: function () {
          return !userProfile.anonymous;
        }

      });
    });
  };

  return fetchUserProfile();

}])
```

`Auth` is in charge of requesting the server, to know the user profile (linked to an access token attached to the request for example):

```js
.service("Auth", ["$http", function ($http) {

  this.getProfile = function () {
    return $http.get("api/auth");
  };

}])
```

The server is expected to return such a JSON object when requesting `GET api/auth`:

```js
{
  "name": "John Doe", // plus any other user information
  "roles": ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"], // or any other role (or no role at all, i.e. an empty array)
  "anonymous": false // or true
}
```

Finally, when `Access` rejects a promise, if using `ui.router`, the `$stateChangeError` event will be fired:

```js
.run(["$rootScope", "Access", "$state", "$log", function ($rootScope, Access, $state, $log) {

  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    switch (error) {

    case Access.UNAUTHORIZED:
      $state.go("signIn");
      break;

    case Access.FORBIDDEN:
      $state.go("forbidden");
      break;

    default:
      $log.warn("$stateChangeError event catched");
      break;

    }
  });

}])
```

If using `ngRoute`, the `$routeChangeError` event will be fired:

```js
.run(["$rootScope", "Access", "$location", "$log", function ($rootScope, Access, $location, $log) {

  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
    switch (rejection) {

    case Access.UNAUTHORIZED:
      $location.path("/signin");
      break;

    case Access.FORBIDDEN:
      $location.path("/forbidden");
      break;

    default:
      $log.warn("$stateChangeError event catched");
      break;

    }
  });

}])
```

---

The user profile can also be accessed in the controllers:

```js
.state("home", {
  /* ... */
  controller: "HomeController",
  resolve: {
    userProfile: "UserProfile"
  }
})
```

`UserProfile` then contains the properties returned by the server when requesting `GET api/auth`:

```js
.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", "userProfile", function ($scope, userProfile) {

  $scope.title = "Hello " + userProfile.name; // "Hello John Doe" in the example

}])
```

---

`UserProfile` needs to be refreshed when a user signs in or out, so that `Access` can handle the routes with the new user profile. You can either reload the whole page, or call `UserProfile.$refresh()`. Example when signing in:

```js
.service("Auth", ["$http", function ($http) {

  /* ... */

  this.signIn = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post("api/auth", credentials).then(function (response) {
      // authentication succeeded, store the response access token somewhere (if any)
    });
  };

}])
```

```js
.state("signIn", {
  /* ... */
  controller: "SignInController",
  resolve: {
    /* ... */
    userProfile: "UserProfile"
  }
})
```

```js
.controller("SignInController", ["$scope", "$state", "Auth", "userProfile", function ($scope, $state, Auth, userProfile) {

  $scope.signIn = function () {
    Auth.signIn($scope.credentials).then(function () {
      // user successfully authenticated, refresh UserProfile
      return userProfile.$refresh();
    }).then(function () {
      // UserProfile is refreshed, redirect user somewhere
      $state.go("home");
    });
  };

}])
```

Comment: I like this answer just not the deferred.reject(Access.FORBIDDEN); I would reserve that to api calls (limits exceeded).  From the user perspective when accessing pages they are either OK or UNAUTHORIZED.

Comment: @LeblancMeneses Thanks :) Just to make it clearer: UNAUTHORIZED means *"we don't know who you are, so we can't say if you're authorized to access this resource or not yet, please sign in first"*, while FORBIDDEN means *"we know who you are, and your profile does not allow you to access this resource"*.

Comment: Nice solution, potential fit with Spring authentication on server side

Comment: Will this redirect user on page refresh? As @Gaui pointed out in another solution, page refresh would remove the user authentication info.

Comment: This is working great so far, but how does the user ID get passed in? User.profile makes use of an ID parameter, but I can't see where to send this in? How does refresh then get the correct user profile from the server?

Comment: @Clint The `id` you see isn't used, it's just the pattern I use for every resource. Actually, in this example, `$resource("rest/users/:attr", {}, {...})` is enough.

Comment: @jsbisht It all depends on where you store the access token(s) (see the last snippet). If you *only* store it in JS memory, then yes: F5 will remove auth info. But if you store it in a persistent storage (e.g. cookie/localStorage/sessionStorage), then no: F5 won't remove auth info (as long as you attach the token to every $http requests, or at least to the requests sent to rest/users/profile, as the server is expected to return the profile of the user linked to the attached token). Beware of CSRF when using cookie storage though.

Comment: @sp00m indeed. I did some fiddling and found out that the resource stuff works a particular way. I'm using ASP.NET 5 on the backend, so there was some convention disparity. I'm now using angular-local-storage to store the HMAC key the server is producing, and using an interceptor to add it to the requests. Now I just need to work out the best ways of working with HMAC and securing it all properly... *head spins*

Comment: @sp00m How would we access the authenticated state on a non-route controller, with a watch (to control things like the menu views etc.) ?

Comment: how can i use otherwise function? if logged in state.go to app.dashboard else state.go to access.forbidden

Comment: @ArsenBabajanyan Make the `otherwise` redirecting to the dashboard, and in the dashboard state definition, use `Access.isAuthenticated()`.

Comment: @DeanWhitehouse You can inject `UserProfile` anywhere, and then use `UserProfile.then(function (userProfile) { $scope.userProfile = userProfile; /* + start watching... */ })` for example.

Comment: @sp00m I really don't see how I can login before giving an id so I can get user's properties, and then verify he has access.... Im sooo lost right now, have been searching for days but Im too noob to find out, and Im stuck af !!! help :(

Answer (score 21):

The most straightforward manner of defining custom behavior for individual routes would be pretty easy:

**1) `routes.js`: create a new property (like `requireAuth`) for any desired route**

```
angular.module('yourApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            requireAuth: true // our custom property
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
})
```

**2)  In a top-tier controller that isn't bound to an element inside the `ng-view` (to avoid conflict with angular `$routeProvider` ), check if the `newUrl` has the `requireAuth` property and act accordingly**

```
 angular.module('YourApp').controller('YourController', function ($scope, $location, session) {
     
     // intercept the route change event
     $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (angularEvent, newUrl) {
         
         // check if the custom property exist
         if (newUrl.requireAuth && !session.user) {
             
             // user isn’t authenticated
             $location.path("/login");
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Can we specify 'requireAuth:true' attribute to all the routes in one place?. Because in my scenario their isn't a login page but its getting authenticated from third party rest call. So i wanted to specify in one place, and it should apply for future added routes as well.

Comment: Not that i know of. Perhaps you can check **every** route that DON'T have a special property defined in `routes.js`.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a post a few months back on how to set up user registration and login functionality with Angular, you can check it out at http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx

I check if the user is logged in the `$locationChangeStart` event, here is my main app.js showing this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
 
    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);
 
    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
 
            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
 
            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
 
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }
 
    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }
 
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }
 
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this way is easiest, but perhaps it's just personal preference.

When you specify your login route (and any other anonymous routes; ex: /register, /logout, /refreshToken, etc.), add:

```
allowAnonymous: true
```

So, something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    allowAnonymous: true, //if you move this, don't forget to update
                          //variable path in the force-page check.
    views: {
        root: {
            templateUrl: "app/auth/login/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
    }
    //Any other config
}
```

You don't ever need to specify "allowAnonymous: false", if not present, it is assumed false, in the check. In an app where most URLs are force authenticated, this is less work. And safer; if you forget to add it to a new URL, the worst that can happen is an anonymous URL is protected. If you do it the other way, specifying "requireAuthentication: true", and you forget to add it to a URL, you are leaking a sensitive page to the public.

Then run this wherever you feel fits your code design best.

```
//I put it right after the main app module config. I.e. This thing:
angular.module('app', [ /* your dependencies*/ ])
       .config(function (/* you injections */) { /* your config */ })

//Make sure there's no ';' ending the previous line. We're chaining. (or just use a variable)
//
//Then force the logon page
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, User /* My custom session obj */) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, newState) {
        if (!User.authenticated && newState.allowAnonymous != true) {
            //Don't use: $state.go('login');
            //Apparently you can't set the $state while in a $state event.
            //It doesn't work properly. So we use the other way.
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngLoadingSpinner']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/salesnew', {templateUrl: 'partials/salesnew.html', controller: 'salesnewCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/salesview', {templateUrl: 'partials/salesview.html', controller: 'salesviewCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/users', {templateUrl: 'partials/users.html', controller: 'usersCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/forgot', {templateUrl: 'partials/forgot.html', controller: 'forgotCtrl'});


  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});


}]);


app.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService){
    var routespermission=['/home'];  //route that require login
    var salesnew=['/salesnew'];
    var salesview=['/salesview'];
    var users=['/users'];
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        if( routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1
        || salesview.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1
        || salesnew.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1
        || users.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1)
        {
            var connected=loginService.islogged();
            connected.then(function(msg){
                if(!msg.data)
                {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

**loginServices.js**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('loginService',function($http, $location, sessionService){
    return{
        login:function(data,scope){
            var $promise=$http.post('data/user.php',data); //send data to user.php
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                var uid=msg.data;
                if(uid){
                    scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                    sessionService.set('uid',uid);
                    $location.path('/home');
                }          
                else  {
                    scope.msgtxt='incorrect information';
                    $location.path('/login');
                }                  
            });
        },
        logout:function(){
            sessionService.destroy('uid');
            $location.path('/login');
        },
        islogged:function(){
            var $checkSessionServer=$http.post('data/check_session.php');
            return $checkSessionServer;
            /*
            if(sessionService.get('user')) return true;
            else return false;
            */
        }
    }

});
```

**sessionServices.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
        set:function(key,value){
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function(key){
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function(key){
            $http.post('data/destroy_session.php');
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}])
```

**loginCtrl.js**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService', function ($scope,loginService) {
    $scope.msgtxt='';
    $scope.login=function(data){
        loginService.login(data,$scope); //call login service
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resolve`:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.config(function($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl  : 'app/views/login.html',
        controller   : 'YourController',
        controllerAs : 'Your',
        resolve: {
            factory : checkLoginRedirect
        }
    })
}
```

And, the function of the resolve:

```
function checkLoginRedirect($location){

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        if ($location.path() == "/"){
            $location.path('dash'); 
        }

        return true;
    }else{
        // No user is signed in.
        $location.path('/');
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Firebase also has a method that helps you install an observer, I advise installing it inside a `.run`:

```
.run(function(){

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log('User is signed in.');
        } else {
            console.log('No user is signed in.');
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance an application has two user called ap and auc. I am passing an extra property to each route and handling the routing based on the data i get in $routeChangeStart.

Try this:

```
angular.module("app").config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
            when('/ap', {
                templateUrl: 'template1.html',
                controller: 'template1',
                isAp: 'ap',
            }).
            when('/auc', {
                templateUrl: 'template2.html',
                controller: 'template2',
                isAp: 'common',
            }).
            when('/ic', {
                templateUrl: 'template3.html',
                controller: 'template3',
                isAp: 'auc',
            }).
            when('/mup', {
                templateUrl: 'template4.html',
                controller: 'template4',
                isAp: 'ap',
            }).

            when('/mnu', {
                templateUrl: 'template5.html',
                controller: 'template5',
                isAp: 'common',
            }).                               
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/ap',
            });
   }]);
```

app.js:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function ($rootScope, $location) {                
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.$$route.isAp != 'common') {
            if ($rootScope.userTypeGlobal == 1) {
                if (next.$$route.isAp != 'ap') {
                    $location.path("/ap");
                }
            }
            else {
                if (next.$$route.isAp != 'auc') {
                    $location.path("/auc");
                }                        
            }
        }

    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

All have suggested big solution why you are worrying of session on client side.
I mean when state/url changes I suppose you are doing an ajax call to load the data for tempelate.

```
Note :- To Save user's data you may use `resolve` feature of `ui-router`.
 Check cookie if it exist load template , if even cookies doesn't exist than 
there is no chance of logged in , simply redirect to login template/page.
```

Now the ajax data is returned by server using any api. Now the point came into play , return standard return types using server according to logged in status of user. Check those return codes and process your request in controller.
Note:- For controller which doesn't require an ajax call natively , you can call a blank request to server like this `server.location/api/checkSession.php` and this is **checkSession.php**

```
<?php/ANY_LANGUAGE
session_start();//You may use your language specific function if required
if(isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])){
set_header("200 OK");//this is not right syntax , it is just to hint
}
else{
set_header("-1 NOT LOGGED_IN");//you may set any code but compare that same       
//code on client side to check if user is logged in or not.
}
//thanks.....
```

On client side inside controller or through any service as shown in other answers

```
    $http.get(dataUrl)
    .success(function (data){
        $scope.templateData = data;
    })
    .error(function (error, status){
        $scope.data.error = { message: error, status: status};
        console.log($scope.data.error.status);
if(status == CODE_CONFIGURED_ON_SERVER_SIDE_FOR_NON_LOGGED_IN){
//redirect to login
  });
```

Note :- I will update more tomorrow or in future

Answer (score -1):

You should check user authentication in two main sites.

- When users change state, checking it using `'$routeChangeStart'` callback
- When a $http request is sent from angular, using an interceptor.