# Server authentication on page request in nodeJS, angularJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, routes, passport.js

I am using passport.js for authentication. My requirement is that, anyone should not be able to access a particular page (say, '/restricted'), if one is not logged in.

Right now, in my application, anyone can access "localhost:3000/#/restricted" url directly.

I am able to stop this and allow only logged in users to access the page by using [Rorschach120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149396/rorschach120)'s solution in
[Redirect on all routes to login if not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145871/redirect-on-all-routes-to-login-if-not-authenticated).

But this is done client side and is not that secure, because anyone can access this code from browser.

So I need that the request for my page goes to server, I tried [moka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312722/moka)'s solution in [How to know if user is logged in with passport.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739725/how-to-know-if-user-is-logged-in-with-passport-js):

In **app.js**:

```
app.get('/restricted', loggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
// req.user - will exist
// load user orders and render them
});
```

where the loggedIn() function checks if user is logged in or not.

But this middleware is **NEVER** called and anyone can still access the "restricted" page.
What can I do, so that this gets called?

I am new to AngularJS and NodeJS. Am I doing something wrong here? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware for that purpose.

```
app.get('/secure-route', secureMiddleware, myMethod)

let secureMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {

    authCheck(...)
        .then(function(result) {
            // pass
            next()
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.status(401).json({
                code: 401,
                message: 'restricted route'
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, as described in question. But this middleware never gets called. It directly gets redirected to the page requested. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited my question, mentioning that I am using a middleware similar to the one described in this answer, but it is not called. What should I do so that this is called to to check if user is authenticated?

Comment: Did you set the express app to use the middleware?

Comment: I have written app.use("path to the file containing middleware"), do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Should be app.use(require("path here")).

Comment: Okay, and what about client side Angular routing? I have defined the routing for '/restricted' in $routeProvider, is this alright? Or should I change anything there?