# ng-route does not make template requests

Tags: django, angularjs

I have a django backed angular app that uses `angular-route` to resolve the urls

I have a login system that users a `factory` to verify the authorisation of a user, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller).

Here is a part of my `app.js` file

```
.factory('Auth', function (){
var user;
return {
    setUser : function (u)
    {
        user = u;
    },
    isLoggedIn : function()
    {
        var User = false;
        return User;
    }
}
}
)


.config(
function($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : '/login',
        controller:'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise('/')
}
)

.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {


    if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('DENY');
        event.preventDefault();
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    else {
        console.log('ALLOW');
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});
}])
```

I also have a `watch` set in my `MainCtrl`.

```
        $scope.$watch(Auth.isLoggedIn,
            function(value)
            {
                if(!value)
                {
                    $location.path('/login')
                }
                else
                {
                    $location.path('/home')
                }
            })
```

My issue is that, the `/login` template is never requested, even if I manually try /#/login, no errors in console as well.

Also, the `location.$path('/login')` is also not executed, as page stays right at requested
URL. However, `DENY` gets printed in the console log.

I suspect that it is due to the app.run attribute , as the template gets rendered if I remove the `run` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple : "login" is a state, and you forbid access to any state if the user is not logged in !

You could just change this for example :

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, toState, fromState) {
    if (!Auth.isLoggedIn() && toState == 'login' ){
        console.log('ALLOW');
    }
    else if (!Auth.isLoggedIn() && toState != 'login') {
        console.log('DENY');
        event.preventDefault();
        location.path('/login');
    }
    else {
        console.log('ALLOW');
        $location.path('/home');
    }
});
```

Also if you want to see a very complete auth system in angular.js, have a glance at this : 
https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security