# how to create routemap with angularjs ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am creating web application similar to gdrive or dropbox, when I navigate through my folders through links, i need to get path in url. I need to change the path from client side itself using angularJS.

e.g

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('/root', 
                    {
                     url: "/root",
                     templateUrl: "cloud.html"
                    })
        .state('root.___', 
                    {
                        url: "/root/:path",
                        templateUrl: "cloud.html"
                    })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/root" });
       });
```

The controller and template need not be changed, only the url need to be changed, look like this

```
http://mycloud.com/newfolder/newfolder or http://mycloud.com/newfolder/.../.../../folder
```

How to achieve this in angular js ui-router what need to be filled in the blank space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS- Login and Authentication in each route and controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller)

Answer (score 0):

`___` can be replaced by 'path' or any other state of your choice.

`$stateProvider
        .state('/root', 
                    {
                     url: "/root",
                     templateUrl: "cloud.html"
                    })
        .state('root.path', 
                    {
                        url: "/root/:path",
                        templateUrl: "cloud.html"
                    })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/root" });
       });`

Since you already have param `:path` in your url, it will take care of your URLs.
While using ui-sref, just pass the param `path` along with it.

Like `<a ui-sref="root.path({path:your-path-here})">Path</a>`

You need to remember that states follow hierarchy. Refer [angular-ui's state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) page .

Comment: the cloud.html template is not reloading. the app needs cloud.html reloaded everytime when new url visited

Comment: Why do you need to reload the html file?

Comment: yes the ui-view need to be reloaded, as it changes. like http://myweb/abc is different from http://myweb/abc/abc/abc

Comment: Its not reloaded because both parent and child use the same html file hence, it is cached. How are you handling `ui-view` then, isn't it going to be recursive? `ui-view` inside `ui-view` !!! Show `cloud.html` file, let's see what can be done.