# How to hide some URL (pages) to a not logged user in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm about to create a simple website (to learn Angularjs v1) that displays advertisements and I want to display only 2 pages for the public:
1) page that have the advertisements 
2) And a login page
When the user logged (the admin) he can see the other pages like createAd.html 
Any clue please?

Comment: You might need to look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller

Answer (score 1):

You could store this data in a cookie and read the cookie whether the user is logged in. And when the users logs out, of course destroy the cookie.

Another option would be to store it in a variable in a global service and just have a get in the service to retrieve the value of the cookie.

If using a factory you could simply use:

```
        factory.getAuthToken = function () {
            return _authToken;
        };
```

If you use an authentication token.