# Rejected resolve promise not caught

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working partly from [this](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller/29797145#29797145) answer.

I have this route:

```
.state('barcodeQuery', {
    url:'/barcode',
    templateUrl: templatePath + '_BarcodeQuery.html',
    controller: 'BarcodeQueryCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    requireADLogin: true,
    resolve: {
        user: 'user',
        access: function(user){return user.isAdmin().$promise}
    }
})
```

user.isAdmin looks like this:

```
isAdmin: function() {
    return this.getProfile().then(function(data){
        // then return the response.
        if(data.isadmin) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(false);
        }
    });
},
```

So far as I can tell, everything works to this point. `isAdmin()` does return the proper response, depending on the user.

Things start to go wrong here:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
    console.log("Is this thing on?");
});
```

If `.isAdmin()` rejects the promise, there should be a `$stateChangeEror`, right? But in my code, that doesn't happen. The `console.log("Is this thing on?")` line is never reached. No errors, or anything. The page just renders like normal.

I suspect I've been fouled up in a promise somewhere (that's always where I get fouled up), but I don't see it.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

```
access: function(user){return user.isAdmin().$promise}
```

Should have been this:

```
access: function(user){return user.isAdmin()}
```

The post I linked above claimed that I needed to have `$promise` to make sure the `resolve` waited for the function to return it's promise, but it appears this isn't the case.