# `ui-route` - not able to redirect and not geting the `url` of current state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I am running a function after `route-config`. in the function i am checking the login status, and accordingly trying to redirecting to login page. But it's not working,

here is the function how i call :

```
angular.module('meanOffice')
        .config(routeConfig)
        .run(stateController);


function stateController( $rootScope, auth, authToken, $state ){

         $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(){

            var isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn();

            console.log( $state.current.url )// consoles as ^

            if(!isLoggedIn) {
                $state.go('/'); // Could not resolve '/' from state ''
            }

         })

    }
```

How to fix this? what is wrong here? any one help me.

Comment: any errors ????

Comment: see in comment, `// Could not resolve '/' from state ''`

Comment: check your state declaration and other invocations like attached js...when the router cant find the given state this will arises

Comment: I tried like this `$state.go('login', {});` - there is no error exist. But my page is not redirected to login state, login state is exist already

Comment: try with  $location.path('/login'); or $state.go('/login'); please update your states declaration

Comment: when I added `event.preventDefault(); ` after `$state.go('login');` it works correctly.  But I don't  know the reason for this. can you please explain as answer to this question?

Comment: is it working correctly with another state when your  you are logged in ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**event.preventDefault()**

this will cancel the current event like state changing.....suppose your going to home state with out login then event.preventDefault(); function cancle that and redirect to the given state in state.go

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller)  you can find the clear demonsration for this functionality

Answer (score 0):

"// Could not resolve '/' from state '' " --this error is because there is no state with "/" is present in $stateProvider. Please include one. Had attached sample code for your reference

```
$stateProvider.state("/", {
         url: "/tpl.htmlpage.html",
         templateUrl: "htmlpage.html"
 });
```