# AngularJS how to store session

Tags: angularjs, session

I've found a good flow to manage custom session manage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971528). The question now is concerning on, which is the best way to store that the user is already validated?

For example I have a rest api that return 0 or 1 if user's creadentials are valid. Now, how and where can I store that information? SessionStorage could be good a place but if I store the user's password encrypted for example, then in controller, I have to check against what?? Where is the true and valid encrypted password?

This question is in general, how to manage user session in angularJS.

**EDIT**: Maybe the answer could be, you shouldn't check only credentials in the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just comment if someone helps.

One of the most important thing is activate credentials in `$httpProvider`

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Then in server some cookies must be stored into session and that's all. Next requests now are session-validated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject 'ngCookies' in you app module and inject '$cookies' in your controller

and you can put value like `$cookies.put('variableName', vlue);`.
and you can retrive `$cookies.get('variableName');`

Comment: Thanks! Anyway then I have to check against the server this credentials? Is there any way to (apart of going) to the server, deny access checking it in client side?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you question properly. Is that mean you want to send this data or cookies value to server?

Comment: Me neither :(. I'm not sure what I would like to ask... I will try your approach. Thanks!