# Reading property resolve from angular $routeProvider error

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I am trying to restrict access to some pages within the public directory using Angular routing.

```
.when('/adminprofile', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/adminprofile.html',
    access: {restricted: true}
  })
```

I am trying to read what I believe is a property called access which I declared, called **access**

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
  function (event, next, current) {
    AuthService.getUserStatus()
    .then(function(){
      if (next.access.restricted && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
        $location.path('/login');
        $route.reload();
      }
    });
});
 });
```

But what I get is this error:

> TypeError: next.access is undefined

How can I read the property or how can i achieve this in a better way?, Thanks

EDIT :

According to suggestion, I have changed the code and it looks as it follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
    resolve: { 
      access: false
    }
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
    resolve: { 
      access: false
    }
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController',
    resolve: { 
      access: false
    }
  })
  .when('/logout', {
    controller: 'logoutController',
    resolve: { 
      access: false
    }
  })
  .when('/register', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/register.html',
    controller: 'registerController',
    resolve: { 
      access: false
    }
  })
  .when('/adminprofile', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/adminprofile.html',
    resolve: { 
      access: true
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'

  });

});
```

And I have my run function:

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
debugger;
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
  function (event, next, current) {
    AuthService.getUserStatus()
    .then(function(){
      if (next.resolve.access && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
        $location.path('/login');
        $route.reload();
      } else{
        $location.path($route.current.originalPath);
      }
    });
});
});
```

Now I can see the value of access:

> next.resolve.access

but is not displaying anything, I run in debug and can see that actually is going through the $routeChangeStart callback , whyyyyy?? helppppp!

Comment: try and inspect "next" or console log it to view its contents... is access even in there?

Comment: i was just debugging in chrome and it says undefined when i hover over it

Comment: actually is an Object : params{}, pathParams{}, _proto_: Object

Comment: looking at the documentation ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) there doesn't seem to be an access or the option to add custom properties. You will have to think of another way. Maybe add it as a query parameter? Or have it redirect to the same URL with an access query parameter.

Comment: I read the docs briefly and I know the property itself does not exist, but I saw few other examples and it seems possible to include some parameters as a "json" kind of thing object, like:
> data:{property: value}

Comment: alright this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209203/angularjs-protecting-routes-with-angularjs-depending-if-the-user-is-authorized .. What you want is called a protected route. I can give a quick answer but you will have to apply it to your run block. and I wont be able to test. but you want to resolve: { access: function() { return true; }} and grab that value in your run block

Comment: Thank you , that is what I need, although I am trying what you said:

.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
        resolve: { access: function() { 
          return true; 
        }
      })

I am getting this:  ',' expected

Comment: ok, fixed that, but now is not rendering the template, I will post answer, when sit works again :(

Comment: Please see edit\

Answer (score 0):

ok fellas, is done, this is the right way to do it:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/home.html',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/logout', {
    controller: 'logoutController',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/register', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/register.html',
    controller: 'registerController',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/adminprofile', {
    templateUrl: '../partials/adminprofile.html',
    resolve:  { 
      access: function() {
          return true;
      }
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'

  });

});

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
debugger;
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
  function (event, next, current) {
    AuthService.getUserStatus()
    .then(function(){
      if (next.resolve.access && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
        $location.path('/login');
        $route.reload();
      }
    });
});
});
```

resolve has to be a function

> Resolve will open your route with a resolved variable (that can be injected into controller) as soon as it gets value (instantly or when returned promise will be resolved)

as it was not returning a value, the router seems to be stuck waiting for a value to resolve.