# angularjs redircet to login page if not login

Tags: angularjs

I am using Laravel angularjs

I am using this package `https://github.com/andbet39/tokenAuth`

it's working fine but my problem is without login i can go to any page also once i reload the page user name is disabled

I don't know what is the problem here

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', ['ui.router', 'satellizer'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider,$provide) {

        $authProvider.loginUrl = '/api/authenticate';

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/js/tpl/login.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: '/js/tpl/register.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            })
            .state('todo', {
            url: '/todo',
            templateUrl: '/js/tpl/todo.html',
            controller: 'TodoController'
        });

        function redirectWhenLoggedOut($q, $injector) {
            return {
                responseError: function (rejection) {
                    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
                    var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

                    angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function (value, key) {
                        if (rejection.data.error === value) {
                            localStorage.removeItem('user');
                            $state.go('login');
                        }
                    });

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
        }

        $provide.factory('redirectWhenLoggedOut', redirectWhenLoggedOut);

    });
```

**TodoController.js**

```
app.controller('TodoController',  function($state,$http,$rootScope, $scope,$auth) {

    $scope.todos=[];
    $scope.newTodo={};

    $scope.init = function (){

        $http.get('/api/todo').success(function(data){
            $scope.todos=data;
        })
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
        $http.post('/api/todo',$scope.newTodo).success(function (data) {
            $scope.todos.push(data);
            $scope.newTodo={};
        });
    };

    $scope.update = function(index){
         $http.put('/api/todo/'+ $scope.todos[index].id,$scope.todos[index]);
    };

    $scope.delete = function(index){
         $http.delete('/api/todo/'+ $scope.todos[index].id).success(function(){
             $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
         });
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {
        $auth.logout().then(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    }

    $scope.init();

});
```

**AuthController.js**

```
app.controller('AuthController',  function($auth, $state,$http,$rootScope, $scope) {

    $scope.email='';
    $scope.password='';
    $scope.newUser={};
    $scope.loginError=false;
    $scope.loginErrorText='';

        $scope.login = function() {

            var credentials = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            }

            $auth.login(credentials).then(function() {

                return $http.get('api/authenticate/user');

            }, function(error) {
                $scope.loginError = true;
                $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;

            }).then(function(response) {

               // var user = JSON.stringify(response.data.user);

              //  localStorage.setItem('user', user);
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;
                $scope.loginError = false;
                $scope.loginErrorText = '';

                $state.go('todo');
            });
        }

        $scope.register = function () {

            $http.post('/api/register',$scope.newUser)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.email=$scope.newUser.email;
                    $scope.password=$scope.newUser.password;
                    $scope.login();
            })

        };


});
```

I want to redirect to login page if authandicate is falied

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angularjs 1.4+ there is no

```
    $http.get('/api/todo').success(function(data){
        $scope.todos=data;
    })
```

What you should do instead

```
    $http.get('/api/todo').then(function(data){
        $scope.todos=data;
    })
```

And same with this `$http.post` which you have below.

Also after refreshing page rootScope is deleted and that is why nickname is blank after refresh.

You probably want to store nickname in localStorage or async promise based localForage.

If you chose async localForage on login you can emit custom event with rootScope and execute some function on this event which gather nickname from localForage. You might want to execute this function in some external controller which would wrap all app so when you assign `$scope.nick` you will have access to it across entire app. Same with `$scope.auth = true`, you will be able to build your app basing on this boolean for logged in using `ng-if` directive.

Inject `$location` to your controller as function parameter and try to redirect like so

```
$location.path('/todo' );
```

or

```
$location.url(YOUR_URL);
```

Also I don't really understand why you are doing two backend call for login, one inside another. You probably should do one `$http.post` which would return token in response. Then you could fix and simplify your function code to

```
    $scope.login = function() {

        var credentials = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        }

        $auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;
            $scope.loginError = false;
            $scope.loginErrorText = '';
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.loginError = true;
            $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;
            $location.path('/todo' ); 
        });
    }
```

However I don't know your code from $auth service.

Remember to inject $location service.

Comment: it's not redirecting to login page how to redirect

Comment: Take a look at edit, redirecting via $location doesn't work?

Comment: i need to add error function or what for redirection

Comment: I used that github code only. My problem is without login i can access todo page so i want to restict that if not logged in i want to redirect to login oage

Comment: Like I said you can create externall controller and display data whether user is logged on not using `ng-if` and this boolean from external controller or you can implement something like route guard. Take a look at answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209203/angularjs-protecting-routes-with-angularjs-depending-if-the-user-is-authorized or both

Answer (score 0):

redirectWhenLoggedOut seems to be an http interceptor.

I think the idea is that you redirect when the http call was not successful. So you need to add an http interceptor that catches the http error and redirects to the login page.

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirectWhenLoggedOut');

Don't forget to inject the $httpProvider;